# Regeln für mehrfache indirekte Rede?

Tags: tense, indirect-speech

> Er sagte, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn nicht lieben würde (niemals geliebt haben würde).

Intuitiv würde ich das so formulieren. Bin mir aber unsicher, ob der Konjunktiv im zweiten Teilsatz richtig bzw. nötig ist. Im Netz hab ich nur einfache indirekte Rede gefunden. Zugegeben eher ein Spezialfall.

Wie verfährt man bei drei-/vierfacher indirekter Rede? Doppeltes/dreifaches Plusquamperfekt?

Comment: "Wie verfährt man bei drei-/vierfacher indirekter Rede?" Der Übersichtlichkeit halber würde ich das in einzelne Sätze zerlegen.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Meinung nach ist

> Er sagte, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn nicht lieben würde

richtig.

> Er sagte, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn niemals geliebt haben würde

funktioniert nicht als ganzer Satz, sondern müsste von einem *wenn* oder *aber* gefolgt werden:

> Er sagte, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn niemals geliebt haben würde, wenn er nicht so ein großartiger Mensch wäre.

Comment: `funktioniert nicht als ganzer Satz`? Kannst du mal die Regel/Begründung nennen für diesen Schluss. Wahrscheinlich wg. dem *niemals*, aber Duden sagt schlichtes Adverb wie *nie*. *geliebt haben würde* is Perfekt Konjunktiv. *Ich habe dich niemals/nie geliebt* ist doch ein ganz normaler vollständiger Satz?

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage stellt sich, was der Ursprungssatz war. Es bieten sich an:

- > Ich werde dich niemals/nicht lieben.
- > Ich liebe dich nicht/niemals.

Welches Negationswort verwendet wird, ist nicht wichtig; ich denke aber, dass jeweils das vor dem Schrägstrich besser passt. Wenn wir das in die erste indirekte Rede übertragen, ergeben sich die beiden folgenden Sätze:

- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn niemals lieben werde.
- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn nicht liebe.

In der Schriftsprache sind ausschließlich diese »korrektes Zitieren«. Mündlich wird allerdings gerne ein etwas »würdevollerer« Konjunktiv gebildet, der grammatikalisch jedoch eigentich der Möglichkeit und nicht dem Zitat vorbehalten ist:

- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn niemals lieben (werden) würde.
- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn nicht lieben würde.

Ein wenig sträubt sich mein Sprachgefühl schon dagegen; ich würde fast eine Indikativform gegenüber dieser Konjunktiv-II-Form bevorzugen, die dann doch zu viel der Distanzierung mit sich bringt.

- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn niemals lieben wird.
- > Sie hat gesagt, dass sie ihn nicht liebt.

Zu guter Letzt setzen wir auch diese Sätze in die indirekte Rede. Dabei haben wir schon eine Modusverschiebung durchgemacht; weiter können die Verbmodi nicht verschoben werden. Daher:

- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt habe, dass sie ihn niemals lieben werde.
- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt habe, dass sie ihn nicht liebe.

Natürlich sind auch hier die würdevollen Sätze möglich:

- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn niemals lieben (werden) würde.
- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt hätte, dass sie ihn nicht lieben würde.

Und manchmal begleitet uns auch ein fröhlicher Indikativ:

- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt hat, dass sie ihn niemals lieben wird.
- > Du hast gesagt, dass sie gesagt hat, dass sie ihn nicht liebt.

Eine zweite indirekte Rede wird also deswegen nicht gesondert behandelt, weil sie sich nicht von der ersten indirekten Rede unterscheidet – mit Ausnahme dass in der Regel die Modi bereits verschoben wurden, also nicht nochmal verschoben werden können.